# Combine Debian netinst with a regular partition - USB

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, usb-storage, bootable-media

I wonder if it is possible to have a bootable Debian netinst USB drive while also retaining the ability to store regular files on that same drive. What I would like to have in the end is USB drive that I could insert into a computer and boot Debian installer from; I would also like to be able to insert it into a working computer and use it as a regular USB drive that I can carry my files in. Is it possible? I would be grateful if someone could also provide some instructions on how to achieve that.

As I understand, the solution should probably be a USB with 3+ partitions: an MBR to boot netinst, the netinst partition(s) and an NTFS/FAT/Ext4/??? partition where files could be kept. The problem is that I am not able to use any disk management tool to edit the partition table of a netinst USB.